# flex - getting data from an xml list

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, xmllist

i have a simple xml like so:

```
<root Name="Bob" isImployed="true">
 <customer Name="Bob" id="12345">was addressed in the shopping mall</customer> 
 <Job-title>Insurance</Job-title> 
 <experience>15</experience> 
 <Question1 question="how much do you make?">35000</Question1> 
 <Question2 question="do you get a yearly bonus?">5000</Question2> 
 <Question3 question="would you be interested in our weekly plan?">yes</Question3>
</root>
```

i've created an XMLList containing the data:

```
var mylist:XMLList;
```

I would like to go over all the questions (there are more than question1,question2 and question3). some of those contain numbers (salary, bouns) and some don't. I am looking for a way to go over the whole list, querying if the answer is a number or not, and if so - get the number. (and do some calculation with it). How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: This is pretty awfully formed XML - you really should have a <Questions> tag that contains all of the individual question items instead of them just sort of floating around like that.  If you have any control over the schema I would change it.

Comment: i don't any control of that :(

Comment: Call up the person who made the xml and tell them they are fired

Answer (score 1):

This loop should go thru that xml and read the values of all questions and get the ones that are numbers:

```
for each (var question:XML in mylist..*) {
            if (question.hasOwnProperty("@question") && !isNaN(question.valueOf())) {
                var value:int = question.valueOf();
                // do calclulations on value
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you all the parts you need.

```
<mx:XML id="someXML" xmlns="">
        <root Name="Bob" isImployed="true">
            <customer Name="Bob" id="12345">was addressed in the shopping mall</customer> 
            <Job-title>Insurance</Job-title> 
            <experience>15</experience> 
            <Question1 question="how much do you make?">35000</Question1> 
            <Question2 question="do you get a yearly bonus?">5000</Question2> 
            <Question3 question="would you be interested in our weekly plan?">yes</Question3>
        </root>
    </mx:XML>
    <mx:List dataProvider="{someXML..@question}">
        <mx:itemRenderer>
            <mx:Component>
                <mx:VBox>
                    <mx:Label text="Question:     {data}" fontWeight="bold" />
                    <mx:Label text="{XML(data).parent()}" />
                    <mx:Label text="Is Number:   {isNaN(XML(data).parent())?'No':'Yes'}" />
                </mx:VBox>
            </mx:Component>
        </mx:itemRenderer>
    </mx:List>
```